# flutter run does not work on iOS Simulator but Xcode can build

Tags: ios, flutter, simulator

In my Flutter project, `flutter run` command cannot build project to iOS Simulator but in Xcode when I click build button, Xcode can build it with no problem. I'm using AgoraRTC libraries. After adding Flutter Quill this happened. I deleted all derived datas. Cleaned build folder. Did flutter clean. Rm ios/podfile then pod install, upgrade dependencies etc. but none of them solved my problem.

Do you know how to fix this problem?

```
flutter doctor -v result
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.2.2 at /Users/user/development/flutter
    • Framework revision d79295af24 (3 weeks ago), 2021-06-11 08:56:01 -0700
    • Engine revision 91c9fc8fe0
    • Dart version 2.13.3

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.23.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • 51D141E2-C032-43E0-A6F8-0E6C24D78AEC • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-5 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.114
```

```
warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in '/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/projectx/ios/Pods/AgoraRtcEngine_iOS/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.xcframework AgoraAIDenoiseExtension framework
   ios-armv7_arm64 ios-x86_64-simulator' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).
   warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in '/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/projectx/ios/Pods/AgoraRtcEngine_iOS/AgoraRtcKit.xcframework AgoraRtcKit framework ios-x86_64-simulator
   ios-armv7_arm64' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).
   warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in '/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/projectx/ios/Pods/AgoraRtcEngine_iOS/Agoraffmpeg.xcframework Agoraffmpeg framework ios-armv7_arm64
   ios-x86_64-simulator' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).
   warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in '/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/projectx/ios/Pods/AgoraRtcEngine_iOS/AgoraCore.xcframework AgoraCore framework ios-armv7_arm64
   ios-x86_64-simulator' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).
   warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in '/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/projectx/ios/Pods/AgoraRtcEngine_iOS/AgoraSoundTouch.xcframework AgoraSoundTouch framework ios-x86_64-simulator
   ios-armv7_arm64' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).
   warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in '/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/projectx/ios/Pods/AgoraRtcEngine_iOS/Agorafdkaac.xcframework Agorafdkaac framework ios-x86_64-simulator
   ios-armv7_arm64' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).
   warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in '/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/projectx/ios/Pods/AgoraRtcEngine_iOS/AgoraDav1dExtension.xcframework AgoraDav1dExtension framework
   ios-x86_64-simulator ios-armv7_arm64' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).
```

Comment: Did u find a solution? I face the same problem

Comment: for me only works if I change to flutter channel master. But is not what I want to.

Comment: @YaSi here is the answer I posted to solve the problem above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68224011/7046992